# Passing data remotely and securely to and fro between 2 websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, curl

I have two websites http://example1.com/  and another say http://example2.com/

A Javascript event click on example1.com/ will open a popup of example2.com/ , doing some operations i want to pass some data back to example1.com say with GET and detect it using jQuery or Javascript, not with PHP.

If data is authenticated it will invoke a event in example1.com.

I have tried using $.getJSON , curl from example2.com. but i either can't catch the data through my JS library or getting a CORS Error.

Example of such a behavior would be Facebook comment box, where after authentication Comment Box displays image and name of the person logged in.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you have 2 approaches

1. Use jsonp :- [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)
2. If you are using modern browsers(IE > 8) then you can also use postMessage API
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage
   I have written small blog on this topic you can check [this](http://crossdomainjavascript.wordpress.com/author/sandeeproop/) also.